# Terraform - Enumerating Instances

Tags: terraform

Terraform question here: I am trying to deploy a set of instances on Azure and I am enumerating them when deployed.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "kafka" {   name                   
= "kafka${count.index}"   #name                             = "${var.kafka_cluster_prefix}-kafka-${count.index}"   location         
= "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"   resource_group_name              = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"   #availability_set_id              = "${azurerm_availability_set.kafka.id}"   network_interface_ids            = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.broker_nic.*.id, count.index)}"]   vm_size                          = "${var.broker_vm_size}"   delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true   delete_data_disks_on_termination = true   count                       
= "${var.broker_instance_count}"

  tags {
    displayName = "${var.kafka_cluster_prefix}-kafka VM Creation"
    ssh_user    = "${var.admin_username}"
    ssh_ip      = "${element(azurerm_network_interface.broker_nic.*.private_ip_address, count.index)}"
    role        = "${var.kafka_role_tag}"   }
```

However, my instances are starting count from '0' (i.e., broker0, broker1, broker2).

Question: Is it possible to start counting from '1' and not '0' ?

Thanks again,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - that's how arrays work in any sensible programming language, they always start at 0.

But you have [math operations](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#math) available to you, so why don't you just do a `"${count.index + 1}"` - that will let Terraform iterate over as it expects, and you get to name your resources how you wish.